# Is this even correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs

How is the "I may" part in the following sentence correct? "may" is used for asking permissions politely but here it is not used as a question and yet it is politely structured? Am I missing smth here?

> It is, therefore, requested you that I may kindly be relieved from 25.04.2008 after...

Comment: Isn't "It is ... requested" a formally presented question? For example, a serviceman won't ask his senior officer "May I grow a beard?" but asks "Request permission to grow a beard, Sir!"

Comment: Yeah,I agree with this  "Request permission to grow a beard, Sir!"  BUT You don't really ask  "I Request I may be allowed to grow a beard, Sir!" That just feels wrong, not to your ears?

Answer (score -3):

This is correct after addition of "from" after "requested" and a change of form in the subordinate.

- "It is, therefore, requested from you that you kindly relieve me from 25.04.2008 after..."

If you request a permission, it is for yourself; here somebody else is giving the permission to relieve you, if it is a matter of permission. Supposing it is a matter of possibility, which it is not (kindly), I believe, it is not better.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about "may". I still don't get it, sorry.

Comment: The tenses of your suggestion don't make any sense. Why is *relieved* in the past tense?

Comment: @PeterShor It seems to me the action is a contemplated one, not a realized one, therefore a subjunctive is more usual and as this form is used (same as for the past) for the subjunctive, that is what I use.

Comment: Why is it a request if "you" has already relieved "me"?

Comment: @HotLicks If I were to tell you that '"you" has already relieved "me"' I wouldn't have understood the sentence. That is not what is said in the sentence nor what my sentence says, that is completely off the point.

Comment: "... it is therefor requested that you kindly **relieved** me ..."

Comment: Isn't the correct subjunctive form to use here "relieve" (identical to the indicative)? The verb "request" is used with subjunctive forms such as "be" and "relieve", not "were" and "relieved".

Comment: @TannerSwett From ["Use of the past subjunctive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive), Wikipedia, ("The past subjunctive can also be used in some "that" clauses expressing a wish contrary to fact or unlikely to be fulfilled[…]) it would seem that this is correct; is there anything more to this use of the past as subjunctive that you'd know as preventing its use in this sentence?

Comment: In my experience, the verb "request" requires a present subjunctive; it's never used with a past subjunctive. See if you can find any professionally edited text which uses "request that" with a past subjunctive; I bet you won't find any.

Comment: @TannerSwett After checking plenty of instances (Google Books) I must say that you are right: the present subjunctive is used in an enormous majority them, the modals being used only sometimes and the indicative present only exceptionally (considered as rather erroneous, I believe); I haven't found a single instance of the past.